# Azure Key Vault - Storage and Access for Connection Strings

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I would like to store my Db password in the Azure KeyVault and be able to use it in the connection string in appsettings.json. Is it possible?

---

Things done

- Application is registered and configured with the Azure Key Vault
- Created a secret value of which is identical with my Db password

I can see that my App Service application is configured with the key vault since there is a relevant configuration entry in `launchSettings.json`.
This is what I would like to do in `appsettings.json` :

```
"myContext": "Server=myServer;Database=myDb;User Id=myUser; Password={KEYVAULTSECRET}"
```

Is it possible and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Key Vault references for this. The high level instructions are:

1. Add your secret to Key Vault.
2. Create a managed identity for the webapp which has access to the key vault.
3. Create a key vault reference as the value of an application setting. (App settings are just environment variables.)
4. Finally, in your config file just reference your environment variable ( `... ${MY_DB_PASSWORD} ..`

The official docs on this are here: [Use Key Vault references for App Service and Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references).

---

I wrote an example of this for Java apps [Key Vault References with Spring](https://jasonfreeberg.com/Key-Vault-References-with-Spring/#).